# Burg install error

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, burg

Im trying to install Burg bootloader. OS is Ubuntu 14.04LTS and Windows (unable to access through Grub since the Ubuntu update)
When I run the Grub Customizer I get the following error:

burg-mkconfig couldn't be executed successfully. error message:
 Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try`/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this error:

```
Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
```

To fix this, simply run the next command in the terminal:

```
sudo burg-install "(hd0)"
```

This will integrate the Hard Disk into your burg installation.